# How to make a comment sticky in latest Reddit PRAW lib?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

[This is how it looks in subreddit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu257.png)I hope you are doing great ! The PRAW documentation says that I need to make a comment sticky using

```
.mod.distinguish(sticky=True)
```

but when I try it does not work. I have seen some post which is 4 years old also says it should be done like this. is there anything I am missing ? Below is my code, please do check it. Thank you so much

```
cmt = submission.reply(get_table())
cmt.mod.distinguish(sticky=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? What happens? You presumably need to be a moderator of the subreddit to sticky a comment. Are you?

Comment: yes, I am moderator. the commend is posting as mod but can not make it sticky. I just notice when I click the shield button on the comment I see no option as sticky but when I click shield button in a post, it shows the make it sticky thing. any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used PRAW in a long time, and I don't have the ability to run any tests now. I might be able to do some tests later in the week. Hopefully someone else who is more current on PRAW is able to answer your question before then